# cmd: how to extract 2 colums from csv?

Tags: csv, batch-file, cmd, extract

I have a csv with 29 colums, i only need 6 and 7 to copy files to a different folder.
there are some empty fields in column G, so i want to skip these lines.

i thought i could forego assigning all variables, but when the code did not work i wrote them all out...alas that did not help me solving this :)

my script appears to be stuck without the variables.
since it does not work as i expected and i do not understand what i did wrong.
can somebody explain what i missed?

'''

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET pathname=E:\2021\1130
SET inputfile=%pathname%\test.csv

FOR /F "tokens=1-29* delims=," %%A IN (%inputfile%) DO (
    Set "var1=%%A"
    Set "var2=%%B"
    Set "var3=%%C"
    Set "var4=%%D"
    Set "var5=%%E"
    Set "var6=%%F"
    Set "var7=%%G"
    Set "var8=%%H"
    Set "var9=%%I"
    Set "var10=%%J"
    Set "var11=%%K"
    Set "var12=%%L"
    Set "var13=%%M"
    Set "var14=%%N"
    Set "var15=%%O"
    Set "var16=%%P"
    Set "var17=%%Q"
    Set "var18=%%R"
    Set "var19=%%S"
    Set "var20=%%T"
    Set "var21=%%U"
    Set "var22=%%V"
    Set "var23=%%W"
    Set "var24=%%X"
    Set "var25=%%Y"
    Set "var26=%%Z"
    Set "var27=%%AA"
    Set "var28=%%AB"
    Set "var29=%%AC"
    CALL :OUTPUT
)

:OUTPUT
IF NOT DEFINED [%var7%] echo goto next record
IF [%%G] == [] Echo missing value
echo copy %%F/%%G %pathname%/%var6%/%var7%
```

'''

Comment: you want only token 6 and 7. Why don' you use `tokens=6,7` then?

Comment: `FOR /F "tokens=6.7 delims=," %%A IN (%inputfile%) DO if  "%%B" == "" (echo missing value) else copy "%%A\%%B" "%pathname%\%%A\%%B"`

Comment: FOR /F "tokens=6,7  
thank you that solved it, i started out with only 6 and 7 but could not get that to work, and i still don't know what's wrong with my code, but i'm happy with this solution.
short and efficient.

Comment: You will not recognise empty values with `for /F` since it treats multiple delimiters `,,` as one. Also you do not have to extract all 29 tokens when you just need two of them. Anyway, it would help when you share a few lines of your input file and also the related desired output. It does not make any sense to assign the `for` meta-variables to "normal" environment variables as you could use the latter immediately…

Comment: three main errors in your code: `%%AA` will translate into the value of `%%A plus an additional literal `A` (`for` variable names are one-char only) and `%%x` variables are not defined outside the loop (e.g. in your called subroutine) and it should simply be `if not defined var7 echo ...`

Comment: thanks, i grasp it a lot better now :)